# Canvas de fondo en la web - posición absoluta en css

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Estoy haciendo una web, tengo un código externo en canvas (una bola del mundo que se mueve), y para ponerle el texto encima normal, sólo me deja hacerlo poniéndole una posición absoluta al canvas, (lo que genera que body, ya no sea el padre, y me hace un gran espacio en blanco al final del todo...) os pondría el código, pero es grandecito...

¿Alguien sabe alguna manera de poner un código canvas de fondo, para añadir texto por encima de "esa capa", sin usar posición absoluta?

Gracias por la ayuda por adelantado,

Comment: ¿Con posición absoluta te refieres a `position: fixed;`? Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] para entender por qué es mejor que crees un [mcve]

Comment: podrias usar algo como esto....style="position:fixed; top:0;left:0"

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, he probado con: .canvas2{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
 }
 #canvasOne2{
    position: relative;
    z-index: -10000;
 }; -------> lo que hace que no me sobre espacio al final, perooo tampoco me aparecen el resto de secciones que yo tengo añadidas a la web, y en consecuencia, no me sirve esta opción...

Comment: Hola Elena, por favor añade el código relacionado con la pregunta para que podamos verlo. De lo contrario la pregunta pueda acabar cerrada al no contener la información necesaria para ayudarte. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: En este pen [labyrinth](https://codepen.io/tmrDevelops/pen/avrZjr?editors=0010) la función txt se encarga de escribir texto en canvas. Podrías probar algo así. Si esto no ayuda, por favor añade tu código

Comment: Si, con insertarle en el canvas el título funciona muy bien (como en labyrinth), pero no quería tocar mucho el canvas por que al ser un código externo, me requería mucho tiempo tocarlo (soy muy nueva, soy becaría de frontend), pero agradezco mucho lo que me habéis puesto, y si veo que me da tiempo, lo haré de esa manera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhhh!, ya me ha pasado eso una vez!, yo intente hacer algo así y me di cuenta que para poder hacer lo que requieres debes hacer lo siguiente en css:

```
html,body{

 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

}

canvas{

 display: block;
 position: absolute;

}
```

Al canvas no le recomiendo que le pongas width: 100% y height: 100%, tampoco te recomiendo que uses la función window.onresize y hagas cambios al ancho y alto del canvas desde js para que se adapte al tamaño de la pantalla, lo que te recomiendo es que cambies el ancho y alto de la pantalla en js con un requestAnimationFrame o un setInterval, ya que si usas window.onresize, al hacerlo te dejara ciertos espacios blancos al lado izquierdo o derecho del canvas:

```
window.onload = ()=>{

    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    requestAnimationFrame(()=>{

         const cWidth = window.innerWidth;
         const cHeight = window.innerHeight;
         canvas.width = cWidth;
         canvas.height = cHeight;

    });

}
```

Comment: Otra cosa, si lo que deseas es solo poner texto (No otros elementos HTML), hay una forma mucho mas sencilla y mejor de realizarlo.

Comment: mil gracias!!! voy a probarlo ahora, ;)

Comment: Veo que te ha funcionado, espero que haya sido de ayuda ;3

Comment: sí, me ha funcionado!! gracias!!